# How to Visualize Unique Cumulative Sum In Elasticsearch/Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a large index that contains data in the following format

```json
{
   "metadata": {"timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"},
   "input": "input_1",
   "output": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

Sometimes the same input results in different output e.g

```json
{
   "metadata": {"timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"},
   "input": "input_1",
   "output": ["a", "b"] <---- Missing "c"
}
```

```json
{
   "metadata": {"timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"},
   "input": "input_1",
   "output": ["a", "b", "c", "d"] <----- "d" Added
}
```

I want to visualize only the upward trend grouped by the input meaning if

`input_1` resulted in `a, b, c` at T then, `input_1` resulted in `a, b` in T+1.
I want to visualize at T and T+1 the number of outputs related to `input_1` is 3.
keep in mind I'm looking for a unique count.

Please note that I'm looking for a way without reindexing or using pipelines as the data
is already there and enormous.

I'm not an Elasticsearch expert so I hope I'm using the correct terms here, and the solution to my problem can be done within elasticsearch. I tried looking online but most of the guides talk about a cumulative sum and I'm looking for a unique cumulative sum